# Evaluating expressions in printf in C

Tags: c, printf, operation

Please have a look at the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int a = 2023;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d",a!=2024,a=2021,a==2021);
}
```

Why does it print **1    2021    0** and *not* **1    2021    1** ?

Comment: Because the order of arguments evaluation is not specified.

Comment: The first line sets 'a' to 2023. The last expression in printf compares 2023 to 2021 and correctly says they're not equal (boolean equal is non zero)

Comment: Why are they evaluated right to left, any specific reason?

Comment: @Jay Explain this then: https://ideone.com/dC0OkR :)

Comment: @Aevo Because it is allowed by the C standard, and the compiler writers decided that it is more optimal for them.

Comment: I don't believe the parameters are guaranteed to be evaluated in any order. So it depends on how the compiler author wrote it. Don't do stuff like this if you want to retain your sanity. ;)

Comment: @Aevo - It is not uncommon for variadic parameters to be evaluated right to left, because if pushed to the stack it is an advantage to have the format string appear on top. But that is just an implementation choice.

Comment: Re “Why are they evaluated right to left, any specific reason?”: Historically, it was common for arguments to be pushed onto the stack one at a time, with a processor  “push to the stack” instruction, and the last argument was pushed to the stack first, so the called routine, as it examined the stack starting from the top of the stack, would see the first argument first. In that situation, the calling routine has to have the last argument’s value before it can push the next-to-last argument’s value. So it made sense to evaluate right to left…

Comment: … Nowadays, that motivation is largely gone. Compilers optimize a great deal, and arguments may involve diverse subexpressions, including some common expressions, so it may make sense to evaluate part of one argument, then part of another, then some common subexpression, then finish another argument, and so on. Also, the compiler may plan stack space and write argument values directly to their assigned locations, rather than pushing them in order…

Comment: … It would not surprise me if there is some residue from ancient code in the compilers that defaults to evaluating arguments right-to-left if nothing disrupts the evaluations, but it is not something you could rely on.